# How to add custom transformation to docker image debezium/connect

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I created a custom MergeField jar file and copied it to debezium/connect:1.6 image to create a new image "connect-test".

```
FROM debezium/connect:1.6
COPY MergeField /kafka/plugins/MergeField
```

Then run my yaml file and specified the plugin path

CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/kafka/plugins/,/kafka/connect

```
connect:
image: connect-test
container_name: connect
ports:
 - 8083:8083
 - 5005:5005
links:
 - kafka
 - elastic
 - zookeeper
 - schema-registry
environment:
 - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
 - GROUP_ID=1
 - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
 - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
 - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_source_connect_statuses
 - KEY_CONVERTER=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
 - VALUE_CONVERTER=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
 - INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
 - INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
 - CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://schema-registry:8081
 - CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://schema-registry:8081
 - CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/kafka/plugins/,/kafka/connect
```

From the log file, it looks like the custom transformation was loaded.
[Kafka-connect log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7BPm.png)

```
"transforms.MergeFields.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MergeField$Value",
        "transforms.MergeFields.field.list":"__table,Id",
        "transforms.MergeFields.field.root":"uniqueId"
```

Adding the connector with the custom transformation gave this error

```
{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):\nInvalid value org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MergeField$Value for configuration transforms.MergeFields.type: Class org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MergeField$Value could not be found.\nInvalid value null for configuration transforms.MergeFields.type: Not a Transformation\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}
```

Which I think is because kafka connect could not find the custom transformation.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms` package for your SMT?

Comment: Yes, I'm using org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms